# How to change an ImageView on button click in android?

Tags: android

I tried creating a practice app that changes `ImageView` on button click to another image. The app is crashing. I want the app to change the image on screen to another image on button click.

LOGCAT :-

```
06-11 09:15:17.860 10063-10063/com.example.myapplication3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication3, PID: 10063
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060055
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1366)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:86)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
    at com.example.myapplication3.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5233)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21211)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    06-11 09:15:17.860 10063-10063/com.example.myapplication3 D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
```

The Java code :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn;
TextView txt;
ImageView imgView1 ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
    txt = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    imgView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txt.setText(getString(R.string.ChangedValue));
            imgView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
        }
    });




}
}
```

The following is the XML file :-

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="304dp"
    android:layout_height="367dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Change "
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="CHANGE" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Provide crash log ..

Comment: Paste Crash logs?

Comment: Check `R.drawable.add` in default drawable folder .

Comment: Are you sure you have added your drawable resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error:-  Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060055

ResourcesNotFoundException means as [Developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.NotFoundException) is thrown by the resource APIs when a requested resource can not be found.

**In Simple words, the drawables, dimensions, layouts, strings or any other resources you are trying to use will not present in your project.**

Solution:- Kindly go through all the resources and check the spelling of its name. Any small mistake gives us an Exception like this.

Feel free to ask more queries.